# Adding Descriptions to custom ArcToolbox 9.3.1

Tags: python, arctoolbox

I looked http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgiSDEsktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Setting_script_tool_parameters and couldn't find how to add Descriptions for each parameter in the script tool.  I see how to add a description for the overall script tool but not for each parameter.

Answer (score 3):

I think reading the ESRI Help on documenting tools and toolboxes should guide you through this process:

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=An_overview_of_documenting_tools_and_toolboxes

Comment: And if you are planning on going with 10.0 soon it is a little different: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001500000014000000.htm

Comment: Read that and that let's me do limited documentation.  What I want to do is to have a description for each input(parameter) in the script tool's dialogue box but I can't seem to find where that needs to happen.  I see that there is an option to reference a xsl file but I don't see any documentation on that in the esri resources.

Comment: Anyone have links from the help on how to leverage these files?  C:\Users\justin\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.0\ArcToolbox\Dlg\MdToolHelp.htm